# Why doesn't my expo react search bar work?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, expo

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { VStack, Input, Icon,  Divider, Heading, Box, FlatList, Center, NativeBaseProvider, Text } from "native-base";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export default function Stocks() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/all");
    const data = await resp.json();
    setData(data);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <Box px={16} py={2} rounded="md" bg="primary.900" my={0.5}>
        {item.symbol}
        {item.name}
      </Box>
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Center flex={1}>
      <Box> Fetch API</Box>
      <SearchBar />
        {loading && <Box>Loading..</Box>}
        {data && (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
          />
        )}
      </Center>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}

function SearchBar() {
  return <VStack my="4" space={5} w="100%" maxW="300px" divider={<Box px="2">
          <Divider />
        </Box>}>
      <VStack w="100%" space={5} alignSelf="center">
        <Heading fontSize="lg">Search for stocks</Heading>
        <Input placeholder="Search" variant="filled" width="100%" borderRadius="10" py="1" px="2" InputLeftElement={<Icon ml="2" size="4" color="gray.400" as={<Ionicons name="ios-search" />} />} />
      </VStack>
    </VStack>;
}
```

When I run the program on my android virtual machine, all my items display as they should and there is a search bar, but when I try to search for the symbol (item.symbol), nothing happens. The search bar is just there, but is not actually connected to my API. Do I need to put something in my fetch?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @thehealeper67 not sure if you fixed it, but I'd expect to find a method inside your SearchBar that will be updated when value will change (onChangeText - in SearchBar from react-native-elements) and also, you'd need some function that uses the current value of the SearchInput and filter your data. You can check this maybe: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-searchbar-in-react-native/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is best to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. A code example can be very useful. Link-only responses may become invalid if the linked page changes.